# Beta testing. Use HockeyApp without using provisioning profiles

Tags: android, ios, beta-testing

I want to use the `HockeyApp` to beta test an application iOS and Android but if it is possible without using provisioning profiles.

An Expected behaviour should be:

- You can open an URL;
- There you can register yourself;
- It's NOT necessary to create a provisioning profile in iTunes connect;
- On the iPhone it might be needed to configure the app as trusted;

Is it possible somehow? And if yes, how can I do this?
I don't want other applications, just `HockeyApp`

Answer (score 3):

On iOS, it is **not** possible to run an app without a provisioning profile. Every app needs to be signed with developer certificate and some form of provisioning profile.

There is a way to avoid the collection of UDIDs by using the Apple Enterprise program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/
However, the license terms of the Enterprise program limit distribution of apps signed with such a provisioning profile to internal employees or devices only.